# How do I use inherit on min-width in CSS?

Tags: html-lists, inheritance, css

This seems really simple, but I can't get the syntax correct w/ the following scenario.  I have some dropdown menus defined for the top of a screen.  I want the list-items (each LI) to be AT LEAST as wide as its parent LI.  It seems like an easy job for min-width and inherit, but I haven't been able to get it to work properly.

Right now, the "inherit" word just gets underlined in VS as if it's not recognized.  The page will build/load fine, but it's clearly not reading the argument, as the LI controls aren't as wide as their parent LI's.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<ul id="javascriptDDM">
    <li><a href="#"> MAIN OPTION 1 </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=1"> Choice 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=2"> Choice 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=3"> Choice 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="../mainPage.aspx"> MAIN OPTION 2 </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=1"> Choice 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=2"> Choice 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="../somePage.aspx?type=3"> Choice 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

... EDIT - here is ALL of the javascriptDDM CSS:

```
#javascriptDDM { width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0 }    
    #javascriptDDM li { width: auto; float: left; list-style: none }
    #javascriptDDM li a { display: block; background: #606668; padding: 5px 12px; text-decoration: none; border-right: 1px solid white; border-top: none; color: White; white-space: nowrap; background-position:left center; }
    #javascriptDDM li a:hover { background: #999999; color: #FFFFFF; }
        #javascriptDDM li ul { width: auto;    margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute;    visibility: hidden; z-index: 1000 }        
        #javascriptDDM li ul li { min-width: inherit; float: none;    display: inline }        
        #javascriptDDM li ul li a{ color: #FFFFFF;background: #999999 }        
        #javascriptDDM li ul li a:hover { color: #000000; background: #FFFFFF}
```

Comment: What's the `min-width` of `#javascriptDDM li ul li`?

Comment: I don't explicitly define the width of any of the other #javascriptDDM controls, so they're just using auto.

Comment: Then what do you expect the `a` to inherit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit will make the `min-width` property take the same "specified" value as the parent's `min-width` property. If you don't set `min-width` on a parent element, it won't have any value.

Comment: The parent elements are all going to be AUTO though, because they contain text of varying lengths.  If I set a parent to have AUTO, and it renders a width of 120px, what will the child's width be?  Will it be AUTO or 120px?

Comment: In my case, setting the width on the parent controls wasn't going to help, because the width was AUTO.  I'm going to use a bit of javascript to dynamically get/set widths.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should set your LI display mode to block.  In this case, you will be at least able to control width of it.

Answer (score 1):

WEFX

Only "block level" elements will inherit the width of their parents. The "a" element is not inherently a "block" level element.

So, to remedy this, you should either add a "display:block" to the "a" element, or, instead, place the min-width CSS on the li instead of the a.

Comment: I've added min-width to the li (see question edit above)... to no avail.